# Redirecting user at login page when he tap on a CTA that require it?

Tags: interaction-design, games

I’m designing a game’s mobile application. In this application there is the possibility to validate the game you played: in a store or in app.
We have two type of users:

1. Guests who are able to access the app and prepare the game but only validate in store.
2. User logged-in who are able to access the app, prepare the game and validate in app.

The interface is quite the same for both types of user with one difference: we have an header that changes. If you are a guest you’ll find a CTA “Sign-in”, in the other case you’ll find your balance and a CTA to charge it. 
At the bottom, for the both users you find 2 CTA:

1. Play online (as main CTA)
2. List item
3. play in store (as secondary CTA)

Here is our doubt: Which is the best interaction, according to your experience, on the main CTA?
We thought these three scenarios:

1. CTA “play online” activated and bring the user on the sign-in/up page
2. CTA “play online” activated and when user tap on it, it’ll appear a popup message
3. CTA “play online” disabled because there is already the CTA sign-in in the header

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell your header is like a main account status:
 - logged in, stating "username" with a balance and "Charge" CTA
 - guest, stating "guest" with no additional info

Now, sign up process is related to account.
If users can play game without registering then there should be a separate CTA for creating account (it's a separate process from playing game itself). That CTA should be in header.

On the other hand, if your game requires new players to create an account, then sure, go ahead and offer them an account creation screen after clicking on main CTA (if possible within the app itself so that users don't need to leave come back afterwards).

In that case you don't need an CTA in header for creting new account, just "Charge" CTA for existing users.

But if your app allows players to continue playing as guests, then after clicking on main CTA offer them a screen where they have 2 options - "Continue as guest" or "Create new account".

In that case there is still an optional CTA in header for new users to create account with, and playing new game just reminds them that there is an option (and possible benefit) for creating new account.

That way they don't feel forced and can choose their own time to make an account.